# Hibernate, JDBC: Error calling Driver#connect

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I try to use Hibernate to connect to my database. But when I build my SessionFactory, it always throws a JDBCCOnnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
at HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:19)
```

Code:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");         
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder sb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
    sb.applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
    StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry = sb.build();                   
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(standardServiceRegistry); //<-- Exception here
    System.err.println("configuration done");
```

The hibernate.cfg.xml file was loaded complete and successful.
I also added, the mysql-connector-java-5.1.29.bin.jar to my buildpath.

Comment: Is it a webApplication ??

Comment: No, till now it is just a class with a main method

Comment: check the hibernate.cfg.xml file ...parameters..some thing may be wrong in that

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of your configuration file.

Check you Sid in

> ```
> hibernate.cfg.xml file
> ```

For Oracle Express Edition:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
```

For Oracle Enterprise Edition:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property>
```